# unordered_map element being deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I'm inserting a `{string, MyStruct}` object in to an unordered_map, later iterating through the unordered_map and choosing to erase the element. However, before erasing the element I have an assert which is showing the unordered_map is empty.

This is my insert:

```
my_umap.insert(std::make_pair(key.toString(), my_struct));
```

The struct contains a member recording the time at which it was inserted. I then periodically check the map and remove elements which have been in the unordered_map for too long:

```
for(auto it = my_umap.begin(); it != my_umap.end(); ++it){

    MyStruct& myStruct = it->second;
    const bool deleteEntry = myStruct.ts.IsElapsed(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    if(deleteEntry){
        const string& key = it->first;    // Cannot access memory for 'key'
        assert(my_umap.size() >= 1);       // This is failing
        my_umap.erase(key);
    }
}
```

I am running the code in gdb and the assert fails. When I query the value of `key` it says

> cannot access memory

When I query the size of `my_umap` it says the size is zero.

How can the for loop detect an element if the size of the unordered_map is zero? There are no other threads accessing this container. I thought `unordered_map::insert()` copies the object in to the container, so the original object being deleted shouldn't matter?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Erasing a container while iterating over it is asking for trouble though.

Comment: The loop iterator it becomes invalid when you erase and ++it does idiocies.

Comment: @ÖöTiib must I add the key to a vector and then loop through that to erase?

Comment: Smells like a threading bug to me. Are you running any threads that might be deleting from this structure at the same time? If that is happening without locks, that is a bad thing.

Comment: It should be possible in the future to close questions as duplicates of [documentation topics](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/511/stdvector/2156/deleting-elements#t=20160809151109566628)

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper Well, if anything it'd be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/681/maps/2239/deleting-elements).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After you call `my_umap.erase(...)`, your iterator becomes invalid:

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) says:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other iterators and references are not invalidated.

This means that once the item is erased, the iterators that pointed to it are no longer valid.

You've got a couple of options:

## 1. Use the iterator to erase, and use the return value of `erase()`

Since C++11, erasing by iterator will return an iterator pointing to the next item in the map. So you can use this to keep your iterator valid:

```
auto it = my_umap.begin();

while (it != my_umap.end()) {

    MyStruct& myStruct = it->second;
    const bool deleteEntry = myStruct.ts.IsElapsed(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    if(deleteEntry){
        assert(my_umap.size() >= 1);
        it = my_umap.erase(it);  // <-- Return value should be a valid iterator.
    }
    else{
        ++it;  // Have to manually increment.
    }
}
```

## 2. Store your iterators in a list object and erase after iteration.

Alternatively, you can store delete candidates in a list object (e.g. vector and delete them after your initial iteration:

```
std::vector<MapType::iterator> deleteCandidates;

for(auto it = my_umap.begin(); it != my_umap.end(); ++it){

    MyStruct& myStruct = it->second;
    const bool deleteEntry = myStruct.ts.IsElapsed(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    if(deleteEntry)
        deleteCandidates.push_back(it);
}

for (auto it : deleteCandidates) {
    my_umap.erase(it);
}
```

---

As for why your assertion is failing, you're probably encountering undefined behaviour by accessing an invalid iterator, making your `for` loop believe that the map is still not empty (because `invalidIterator != my_umap.end()`).

Answer (score 8):

`erase()` invalides the iterator you're erasing. When you subsequently increment it in the `for` loop, you get undefined behavior. The `assert()` is likely triggering on the second iteration of your loop, not your first.

You'll have to restructure your loop like:

```
for(auto it = my_umap.begin(); it != my_umap.end(); /* nothing */){

    MyStruct& myStruct = it->second;
    const bool deleteEntry = myStruct.ts.IsElapsed(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    if(deleteEntry) {
        // either use the return
        it = my_umap.erase(it); // NB: erase by it, not by key, why
                                // do an extra lookup?       

        // or post-increment
        my_umap.erase(it++);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer `it = map.erase(it)` to `map.erase(it++)` but YMMV.

I'd just wrap that in a function template so you don't have to keep rewriting this sort of thing:

```
template <class Container, class F>
void erase_if(Container& c, F&& f) {
    for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ) {
        if (f(*it)) {
            it = c.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
erase_if(my_umap, [](const auto& pr){
    MyStruct& myStruct = pr.second; 
    return myStruct.ts.IsElapsed(std::chrono::seconds(5));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `erase_if()` that @barry suggested is already part of the TS Library Fundamentals V2 (Uniform Container Erasure).
I can't find right now if it's going to be part of C++17.

Here is a reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/unordered_map/erase_if

The standard library shipped with Visual Studio 2015 implements it already.

From the status page of `libstdc++` (the standard library shipped with gcc) we can see that it implements it too, but it's only in the development version, not in any specific release. (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z)

Please note that unlike most of the current algorithms, these functions live in the header of the relevant container (not in algorithm header) and they take a reference to the container itself (instead of pair of iterators). These changes are because those functions have to know about the container to implement the loop correctly and use the container member function `erase()`.
As a result, if you want to apply this erasing operation only on a specific range in the container, you still have to use the hand-written loop as described in the other answers (maybe Ranges TS improves this too?).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are messing up with the iterators. When you erase elements in the middle of the iterating, you erase the current iterator that should have led to the next one.

There are a few ways to solve this. The first is something I just copied from the c++ reference:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> c = { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 3,     "three" },
    { 4, "four" }, { 5, "five" }, { 6, "six" } };
    // erase all odd numbers from c
    for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end();)
        if (it->first % 2 == 1)
            it = c.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    for (auto& p : c)
        std::cout << p.second << ' ';
```

Pay attention to the loop. It doesn't advance the iterator. Instead it assigns the iterator to the one returned from the erased element - erase returns the next iterator, or, of not erasing, it advances it explicitly.

The second option to go around this problem is in the following changed I did to the first program:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> c = { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 3, "three" },
{ 4, "four" }, { 5, "five" }, { 6, "six" } };

    // collect all odd numbers from c into a vector
    vector<int> to_delete;
    for (auto pair : c) if (pair.first % 2 == 1) to_delete.push_back(pair.first); 

    // now delete them all
    for (auto k : to_delete) c.erase(k);

    for (auto& p : c)
        std::cout << p.second << ' ';
}
```

This time I collect all the keys in a vector, then scan the vector and erase each key from the map. This way you don't erase from the map while iterating the map.